# Unable to replace "$" in a string

Tags: powershell

I want to replace "$" from a string in PowerShell.
I am trying this:

```
PS> $vars
abcd$
PS> $vars -replace "`$"
abcd$
```

How to replace the "$" in the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-replace` operator uses *regular expressions* for string matching thus you have to escape the dolar using a **backslash**:

```
$vars -replace "\$"
```

Cheers!